# Access to Any Object in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

i create an array of subviews

```
var subviews  = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews
```

type of "subviews" variable is "AnyObject". I try get subview:

```
var subview=subviews[0]
```

but i receive an error:

```
'[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'
```

How to access the elements of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews
```

returns an optional, so you have to unwrap the array from the optional before using it:

```
var subviews  = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews
if let subviews = subviews {
    // Better check for array length before accessing to the 1st element
    var subview = subviews [0]
}
```

Suggested reading: [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_483)